# Reading from database using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

G_ID is an integer column in Groups table. I want the maximum value of it. When I trace below code I receive the error I've mentioned in code. Reader.HasRows equals true during debugging. So why it says "no data is present"

```
SqlConnection sqlc= new SqlConnection("data source=. ; database=LDatabase; integrated security=true");
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select MAX(G_ID) as MAXID from Groups", sqlc);

sqlc.Open();
SqlDataReader Reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
int MaxID = 0;
        if (Reader.HasRows)
        {
            MaxID = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["MAXID"].ToString());// Here I receive this error:  System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
            MaxID += 1;
        }
```

Comment: You need to call `Reader.Read()` before you can access the columns ...

Comment: Better use ExecuteScalar if you retrieving a single value

Comment: @marc_s I did it now but still the same error

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it's integer in the table

Comment: @Behnaz doesn't matter. any value can be retreived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before accessing a DataReader you need to call the method Read to position the reader on the first record

```
SqlConnection sqlc= new SqlConnection("data source=. ; database=LDatabase; integrated security=true");
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select MAX(G_ID) as MAXID from Groups", sqlc);

sqlc.Open();
SqlDataReader Reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
int MaxID = 0;
if (Reader.Read())
{
    MaxID = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["MAXID"].ToString());
    MaxID += 1;
}
```

By the way, your query returns just one row and one column from the DB so a better approach is to use the ExecuteScalar method

```
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select MAX(G_ID) as MAXID from Groups", sqlc);
sqlc.Open();
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (result != null)
{
    MaxID = Convert.ToInt32(result) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure why I have started  thinking in VB lately

Comment: When I execute above code(ExecuteScalar()) I receive this error: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar: CommandText property has not been initialized

Comment: That's strange, the CommandText is the SELECT.... in the command constructor. Are you sure that you are executing the same SqlCommand shown above?

Comment: I also tried this:             sqlc.Open();
            Int32 result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != 0)
            {
                result += 1;
            } but still I get the same error.

Comment: If you try the DataReader version do you get something instead?

Comment: I suggest to use the debugger to see when the property changes. Put a breakpoint on the SqlCommand construction line and then proceed step by step until you reach the ExecuteScalar call. At every step check the property CommandText of the cmd variable

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the reader has rows but you are not reading them. Do this instead (note I'm also wrapping things to make sure they gets disposed properly):

```
SqlConnection sqlc= new SqlConnection("data source=. ; database=LDatabase; integrated security=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select MAX(G_ID) as MAXID from Groups", sqlc);

sqlc.Open();
try {
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        int MaxID = 0;

        while (reader.Read()) {
            MaxID = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["MAXID"].ToString());
            MaxID += 1;
        }
    }
}
finally {
    sqlc.Close();
}
```